# Where the data stored for mongodump archiving mode

Tags: mongodb, archive, mongodump

I just want to know the location for the file `mydb.client.30092022.archive`

```
mongodump --archive=mydb.client.30092022.archive --db=mydb --collection=client
```

PS - I searched for long but unable to find so please help

Comment: current directory, I just ran this on my system & it dumped it to current directory.

Comment: @bog I think default location for mysqldump is `dump/` directory in non-archive mode. While my question is for archive mode

Comment: you said "mysqldump", are you running mysql or mongodb  ??.  
And I said ["current (working) directory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory#In_operating_systems)  not `./dump/`.

Comment: My bad, that's mongodump. Thanks, Yeah it's dumping in the current directory. But how this archive mode is different from normal dump?

Comment: seems its used for quick and dirty way restoration ([1](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#output-an-archive-to-standard-output) & [2](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#copy-and-clone-databases)) also it solves compatibility issue with non Linux OSes (see [warning](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#behavior) ). I would recommend using `--out`  (with `--gzip`) instead of [`--archive`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--archive) unless you have windows/macos host machine.